# RelativeLayout, match parent contains unwanted padding right?

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-custom-view

I have a custom header bar (something like actionbar).

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ibSlider"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/header_branding"
            android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibSlider"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin"
            style="@style/branding_orange"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I'm adding this custom view in my activity, there is padding right that I have no idea comes from where! I have added green background to the view in order to find I'm talking about where.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/headerBar"
            android:background="@color/green"
            class="com.kamalan.widget.HeaderBar"/>

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerBar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code of my HeaderBar.

```
public class HeaderBar extends RelativeLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "HeaderBar";

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageButton ibMenuSlider;

    public HeaderBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public HeaderBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public HeaderBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_headerbar, null);
        addView(view);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
        ibMenuSlider = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibSlider);
    }
...
}
```

Image 1 shows preview of class header (first xml code) and second image displays when it has been added to my activity. I have no idea that green padding comes from where! any idea would be appreciated. thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: on which API level did you get this issue? let me guess... 3.0 and above? try adding a negative marginRight (better use a dimension in the values-11 folder - I also added another dimension in the values-14 folder)

Comment: Thanks Bob, yes, I'm designing the app for 4.0 and above. Adding negative margin is a kand of hackish way although fixes probelem. I don't think is a nice way since we don't know what the problem is :(

Comment: Well, I do think it's something in the new themes. I had the issue in both left and right sides.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the image that I was using as background of Header. Have no Idea why it works on first image but doesn't work on second one. Maybe activity is messing or Theme has bug, as Bob said in comment.

Anyways, I fixed the problem by not using image :)

For other's reference, I changed xml of header as below and I could fix the problem in this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/gray">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ibSlider"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/header_branding"
            android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibSlider"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin"
            style="@style/branding_orange"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/header_divider"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem but i get success when i try customize Actionbar.I am unable to resolve your problem due to absence of drawable and string resource so please provide zip of this one so that i can see directly .....

Comment: Thanks Anil, no problem I could fix that problem by change of my method. Project is accessible via following link but I changed and removed background images :( https://github.com/Hesamedin/AndroidTemplate